# Error on join in ogr2ogr

Tags: shapefile, sql, ogr2ogr, attribute-joins

I am doing an ogr2ogr process where i will be making a join between two tables, imported as shapefiles and .csv to join on a column with idential attributes.

The code i've made so far looks like this:

```
    ogr2ogr -sql SELECT spmgnt100all_netto_rumnr.*, Areas_editeret.csv FROM spmgntall_netto_rumnr.* LEFT JOIN Areas_editeret.csv ON spmgnt100all_netto_rumnr.RUMNR = spmgnt100all_netto_rumnr.RUMNR Areas_Joined.shp spgmgnt_Joined.shp
```

But I am getting an error: *"Error 1: Failed to create directory spgmnt100all_netto_rumnr.*, for shapefile datastore"
ESRI Shapefile driver failed to create spgmnt100all_netto_rumnr.*,*

I suppose the error occurs when the .shp-table is submitted into another format and that is where the driver fails? 
Or maybe it means that ogr2ogr tries to make a shapefile that is the result of the process. And which fails.

But i might also understand the syntax wrong. I've tried to read my way through [`http://www.gdal.org/ogr_sql.html`](http://www.gdal.org/ogr_sql.html)

Answer (score 2):

`FROM` should contain table names, not column names (and `100` is missing here in the table name)

The `ON` part should connect columns from both tables, but you have specified the same table on both sides.

I suggest to put the whole sql statement in quotation marks, single ones for Linux and double for Windows.

The roles of `dst_datasource_name` and `src_datasource_name` are not clear to me. Where does the .csv file appear?

It might help if you add the table structures, or give a link to the files.

Comment: I'd made some changes to the Query. `ogr2ogr -sql "SELECT spmgnt100all_netto_rumnr.*, Areas_editeret.* FROM spmgnt100all_netto_rumnr LEFT JOIN Areas_editeret.Rumnummer ON spmgnt100all_netto_rumnr.RUMNR = Areas_editeret.ADDED_Column" spmgnt100all_netto_rumnr.* Areas_editeret.csv` Now it outputs that it has trouble making the .prj-file.

Comment: What should be the dst_datasource_name? For src_datasource_name, you should specify the .shp file, not `.*`.